# Cakephp 2.3: Build model associations when foreign keys do not match model columns

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-2.0, model-associations

How, generally, can I create foreign keys (ie. columns) in one table that Cakephp associates, by different names, with columns of another model? Incidentally, I am using `bake all` to get started with the standard CRUD set up.

The general form of my question is:

`Table_A` has `id`|`label`|`TableB_labelA_id`|`TableB_labelB_id`

`Table_B` has `id`|`label`

To make the rest of the question less ugly, though, this is my current application:

`games` has `id`|`date`|`us`|`them`

`teams` has `id`|`name`

I assume this can be achieved through aliases, and association definitions alone, but I don't quite get how. It also occurred to me to simply create `Us` and `Them` models that extend `Team`, but this seemed an undue effort.

I've also noticed, in my `Game model` that `Us` and `Them` are listed in the `$belongsTo` array, instead of `$hasMany` which would intuitively have seemed more correct.

Ideas? I'd be most appreciative!

Comment: Do I understand corectly that `Us` and `Them` both are foreign keys to `teams.id`? If this is the case, then `$belongsTo` **_is_ the right relation**

Comment: Ooh, perhaps I've misunderstood this then. In the example above, does the $belongsTo array of my `games` model imply that a game belongs to an `us` and a `them`, or that the list of things that belong to `game` contains `us` and `them`?

Comment: Well, sometimes the name 'belongsTo' is confusing. In your case, a game "belongs to" both You *and* Them; The *game* doesn't own it's players. Some explanation can be found here [on-to-many](http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/one-to-many.html)

Comment: Ahh. Right. Thanks, my thinking on this wasn't as bas as my language might have implied, henh. Appreciate the link, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about only needing alias and proper association definitions. Here's what you neeed.

```
class Game extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Us' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'us'
        ),
        'Them' => array(
            'className' => 'Team',
            'foreignKey' => 'them'
        ),
    );  
}
```

Bake wouldn't be able to help you with this. It can only make it's educated guesses if all naming is as per convention and in this case that's not possible.

Comment: Well thankyou for this, though I feel a bit cheated now because I'd tried this first (it seemed like the intuitive choice) and it hadn't worked. I must have changed something elsewhere that broke it, though, because it works just fine now. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using better fields names than "us" and "them" though. Something like "home_team_id" and "away_team_id" would be much more readable and inline with cake's naming convention of having foreign key field names ending with "_id"

Comment: Thanks, yeah, in fact I have been using "us_id" and "them_id" as in the general form I posted, I just omitted it in the example to cut down on visual clutter. This has made my day go muuuuch smoother though, haha, thanks again. :)

Comment: Always provide the EXACT info when asking for help.